# Getting an AD User Using LDAP Filtering with a Local Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm retrieving a list of users from Active Directory to validate against a different user but I'm having an issue with `Get-ADUser` for the second user.  The first user (which is a collection of users) is rather simple and works fine.  I retrieve the first user like so:

```
$users += Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org" -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*lvl'" -ResultSetSize 5000 -Properties $properties | Select $properties;
```

With the second user (a single instance this time) I'm trying more complicated approach or at least I'm perceiving it as more complicated since it's not working.  The approach is as follows:

```
$compareUser = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org" -LDAPFilter {"(&(Surname=*$lastName*)(GivenName=*$firstName*))"} -ResultSetSize 1 -Properties $properties | Select $properties;
```

What I'm having issues with is using a variable, in this case `$firstname` and `$lastName`, to filter.

`$firstName` and `$lastName` are derived from the first user and are being used to check for other users in AD with that first name and last name.  To hopefully give more context to issue here's the function where this all takes place.

```
Function ComparingUserAccounts([System.Array]$users, $exceptions = @()){
    $notes = "";
    $invalidUsers = @();

    Foreach($user in $users){
        $firstName = $user.GivenName;
        $lastName = $user.Surname;
        $compareUser = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=org" -LDAPFilter {"(&(Surname=*$lastName*)(GivenName=*$firstName*))"} -ResultSetSize 1 -Properties $properties | Select $properties;
        if(($nonAdminUser.SamAccountName -eq "") -or ($nonAdminUser.SamAccountName -eq $null)){
            if(($nonAdminUser.Surname -ne $user.Surname) -and ($nonAdminUser.GivenName -ne $user.GivenName)){
                if(-Not ($exceptions.Contains($user.SamAccountName))){
                    $invalidUsers += $user.SamAccountName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if($invalidUsers.Count -gt 0){  
        $notes += $invalidUsers.Count + " users found without that name."
    }

    return $notes
}
```

Now when I was looking online on how to use variables in an LDAP Filter it said I should be putting `*` around the variable however that didn't seem to work as my evaluation would always return all users as "wrong".  When a user doesn't pass my validation their username gets added to `$invalidUsers` collection.  When I say all the users are "wrong" they all get added to that collection when I know for a fact most of the users shouldn't be there.  Another thing that might be worth mentioning is that if I don't include the `{ }` around the filter I'll get:

> The search filter cannot be recognized

In short my question is,

**How am I supposed to use variables in an LDAP Filter to get an AD User?**

Answer (score 1):

LDAP properties are names differently than Active Directory properties. Try using this as your LDAP filter:

```
"(&(sn=*$lastName*)(GivenName=*$firstName*))"
```

You also need to remove the `{}` from around your filter.

https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/help/csv-import-management/active-directory-ldap-attributes.html

Comment: Well you're probably right so I changed the LDAP properties but my validation is still saying everything is wrong...